# Array of strings being overwritten

Tags: c, string, parsing, iteration, key-value

I have a program that is trying to take a text file that consists of the following and feed it to my other program.

```
Bruce, Wayne
Bruce, Banner
Princess, Diana
Austin, Powers
```

This is my C code. It is trying to get the number of lines in the file, parse the comma-separated keys and values, and put them all in a list of strings. Lastly, it is trying to iterate through the list of strings and print them out. The output of this is just Austin Powers over and over again. I'm not sure if the problem is how I'm appending the strings to the list or how I'm reading them off.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char* fileName = "Example.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char line[512];
    char * keyname = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char)*80));
    char * val = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(char)*80));
    int i = 0;
    int ch, lines;

    while(!feof(fp)){
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if(ch == '\n'){ //counts how many lines there are
            lines++;
        }
    }
    rewind(fp);

    char* targets[lines*2];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
        strtok(line,"\n");
        sscanf(line, "%[^','], %[^',']%s\n", keyname, val);
        targets[i] = keyname;
        targets[i+1] = val;
        i+=2;
    }
    int q = 0;

    while (q!=i){
        printf("%s\n", targets[q]);
        q++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are using `lines` uninitialized

Comment: @mch, seems an answer to me

Comment: `sscanf(line, "%79[^,], %79[^\n]", keyname, val);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the two lines:

```
targets[i] = keyname;
targets[i+1] = val;
```

These do not make copies of the string - they only copy the address of whatever memory they point to. So, at the end of the `while` loop, each pair of `target` elements point to the same two blocks.

To make copies of the string, you'll either have to use `strdup` (if provided), or implement it yourself with `strlen`, `malloc`, and `strcpy`.

Also, as @mch mentioned, you never initialize `lines`, so while it *may* be zero, it may also be any garbage value (which can cause `char* targets[lines*2];` to fail).

Comment: Thank you! That was able to fix it.

Comment: _it may be zero_ : it may be `1`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that's why immediately afterwards I mentioned "it may also be any garbage value"

Comment: Program does not work correctly  If newline does not exist last line. Even secured one more, it will not be used simply.

Answer (score 1):

First you open the file. The in the while loop, check the condition to find \n or EOF to end the loop. In the loop, if you get anything other than alphanumeric, then separate the token and store it in string array. Increment the count when you encounter \n or EOF. Better use do{}while(ch!=EOF);